# Xpath Запрос. Не могу подобрать нужное выражение

Tags: html, xml, запрос, xpath

Посоветуйте каким выражением xpath можно извлечь текст 6JADX-CLLLW-NWO6N-3NZY1-K8NAI-L2FWX?

```
</th>
<th>Описание</th>
<th class="text-nowrap text-right">
<a href="/coupons/?sort=2&sort_d=1">Баллов</a>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="text-muted">22.11.2021</td>
<td>6JADX-CLLLW-NWO6N-3NZY1-K8NAI-L2FWX</td>
<td><span class="text-info text-nowrap"><i class="fal fa-check-circle"></i> Утвержден</span></td>
<td class="td-desc"><span class="text-muted">Купон успешно прошел модерацию</span></td>
<td class="text-right text-success">1000</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="text-muted">19.11.2021</td>
<td>OOA12-S1SY1-WN1Y1-NFHA8-6F78M-OOHWE</td>
<td><span class="text-info text-nowrap"><i class="fal fa-check-circle"></i> Утвержден</span></td>
<td class="td-desc"><span class="text-muted">Купон успешно прошел модерацию</span></td>
<td class="text-right text-success">2300</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="text-muted">16.11.2021</td>
<td>K6835-154VV-9PG9U-UFZRH-GVWSM-6SQYG</td>
<td><span class="text-info text-nowrap"><i class="fal fa-check-circle"></i> Утвержден</span></td>
<td class="td-desc"><span class="text-muted">Купон успешно прошел модерацию</span></td>
<td class="text-right text-success">1300</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="text-muted">14.11.2021</td>
<td>DNIGK-I1M22-UMNPP-YO7S8-MSU5N-NOAAI</td>
<td><span class="text-success text-nowrap"><i class="fal fa-check-circle"></i> Активирован</span></td>
<td class="td-desc"><span class="text-muted">Купон активирован</span><br>29.11.2021 в 22:39&nbsp(UTC+0)</td>
<td class="text-right text-success">1800</td>
</tr><tr>
```

Comment: Недостаточно данных. Если tr уже найден и порядок td всегда одинаков, то просто берём второй: `td[2]`. А так, нужно опираться на какие-то гарантированные элементы. Это может быть имя класса или что-то ещё.

Comment: Дополнил. Если брать именно td[2], то выйдут все значения из подобных tr. Однако необходимо извлечь тот текст, в узле которого существует класс "text-success text-nowrap", т.е. там, где есть текст "Утвержден". Как-то так...